# Dairy blender used for pareve items

Tags: halacha

If a blender is only used for cold items, and kept extremely clean, could it be used with dairy ingredients (like a smoothie), and also for pareve items that will be served with meat (like hummus served at a Shabbat meal)? Thanks!

Comment: David [welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501)

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Hope to see you around!

Comment: Such a question is best for [dinonline](http://dinonline.org/). I'd suggest asking there. Voted to close as off-topic as asking for p'sak halacha.

Comment: @ezra What in this question suggests that he’s asking for a practical reason rather than curiosity? Before jumping the gun you might want to, you know, ask him as to why he’s curious about this oddly specific question.

Comment: @DonielF You could ask that question about all the questions we close because the OP is asking for a psak halacha.

Comment: @ezra It’s not asking in the first person or saying that this came up and he wants to know what to do, and that covers just about all of the ones closed as psak.

Comment: It doesn't sound like the blender ever becomes dairy.

Comment: @DoubleAA, _kavush_, if it’s used the way I use one.